# How to get Last latest value from RecyclerView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am making Garage Application just like Calculator..Taking 2 values from `EditText` and print in third `EditText`.and then it will store all values in `RecyclerView`.**Now issue is I am trying to get the latest Total Gross value ie last row Total Value** I had done all possibly Solution still I am not getting.

Here is my code in Custom Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Employee employee = bank_details.get(position);


    holder.total.setText(employee.getTotal());
    holder.accept.setText(employee.getAcceptmoney());
    holder.given.setText(employee.getGivemoney());
    holder.note.setText(employee.getNote());
    holder.date.setText(employee.getTime());

    int selectedItem = 0;
    if(selectedItem == position)
        holder.itemView.setSelected(true);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return bank_details.size();
}

public void setSelectedItem(int last_pos) {
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView total;
    TextView accept;
    TextView given;
    TextView note;
    TextView date;

    Button edit;
    Button delete;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv= (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        total = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grossIncome);
        accept = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.acceptmoney);
        given = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.givenmoney);
        note = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.note);
        date= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);


    }
}
public Employee getItem(int position) {
    return bank_details.get(position);
}
```

Here is the code of recyclerview:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recyclerview);

    final RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final ArrayList<Employee> arr = InitializeData();

    final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    cu = new CustomAdapter(arr);
    rv.setAdapter(cu);

    int last_pos = cu.getItemCount() - 1;
    cu.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cu.setSelectedItem(last_pos);
    rv.scrollToPosition(last_pos);
}

public ArrayList<Employee> InitializeData() {
    ArrayList<Employee> arr_emp = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Employee> arr_emp_2 = new ArrayList<>();



    DAL dal = new DAL(this);
    dal.OpenDB();
    arr_emp = dal.AllSelectQryForTabEmpData();
    dal.CloseDB();
    return arr_emp;



}
public void setSelectedItem(int position)
{
    selectedItem = position;
}
```

Problem is I want total value and that total value can be used as giving and receiving value ie-**Total+receving Money**,**Total-giving Money**

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change your adapter accordingly to add a new final row.
To do that, alter some methods.

**1) Item Count must be +1**

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return bank_details.size() + 1;
}
```

**2) Display the last value in last row**

Explain to the adapter what to display for the last row of the recyclerview.
Of course, you have to code the `computeTotalValues()` by browsing inside your `bank_details` variable.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (position >= bank_details.size() {

        double totalValue = computeTotalValue();
        //TODO update your holder views to show the total value.

    } else {
        Employee employee = bank_details.get(position);

        holder.total.setText(employee.getTotal());
        holder.accept.setText(employee.getAcceptmoney());
        holder.given.setText(employee.getGivemoney());
        holder.note.setText(employee.getNote());
        holder.date.setText(employee.getTime());

        int selectedItem = 0;
        if(selectedItem == position)
            holder.itemView.setSelected(true);

    }

}
```

**3) Refresh the last row if data is changed**

In the case you change your `bank_details` information while the recyclerview is displayed (set a value, add a value for instance), you need to warn the adapter that the last row must be updated, by using `notifyItemChanged(int position)` ([See docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int))).

Comment: I got all stuffs but what to write in **computeTotalValue()** I am somewhat new in android.

Comment: The contents of this method is pure Java. Just loop into your `bank_details` to calculate your total amount of money you want to display on the last row.